# Function fscanf crash app after first use

Tags: c, file, for-loop, scanf, fclose

If I comment  `fprintf(pf,"1111");` the exe will crash and if I keep it,I get 2/3/2011 (only the first record).If I try to close the file the exe will crash too.

**Is fscanf detecting the end of row as end of file and reads null?**

I tried also close(*pf),it still crash.

fprintf should not be used in final code,I didn't mean to use it ,but when I used it I observed that the exe reads first line succesfully

```
 Data* d;
fscanf(pf,"%d",&n);
d=calloc(n,sizeof(Data* ));
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(fscanf(pf,"%d/%d/%d",&(d[i].zi),&(d[i].luna),&(d[i].an))!=3) break;
    printf("%d/%d/%d ",d[i].zi,d[i].luna,d[i].an);
       // fprintf(pf,"1111"); with this I observed that first data can be read

}
  fclose(pf);
```

input

```
3
2/3/2011
2/2/2012
2/2/2016
```

Comment: sounds like pf is NULL.  Did you check the return code from `fopen`?

Comment: What is the type of `d[i]`? What is the type of `d`?

Comment: @AlexP is a structure

Comment: And you did not post the declarations for `d` why?

Comment: @AlexP because it would have made it too easy for anyone to provide an answer.

Comment: `close(*pf)`? What's `close`? And why are you trying to dereference `pf`?

Comment: @AlexP I edited the declaration

Comment: 1) `d=(Data*)calloc(n,sizeof(Data* ));` --> `d=calloc(n,sizeof(Data));` 2) `for(i=1;i<=n;i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<n;i++){` 3) delete `fprintf(pf,"1111");` 4) `fscanf(pf,"%d",&n);` move to before `d=calloc(n,sizeof(Data));`

Comment: In the statement `d=(Data*)calloc(n,sizeof(Data*))`, `n` is undefined, not to mention that probably `sizeof(Data)` and `sizeof(Data*)` are different.

Comment: @AnT Sorry,I add some pieces and I edited them and are in the right order now

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I updated the code,still doesn't work

Comment: `sizeof(Data* )`  should be `sizeof(Data)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, that is the answer ,it worked.Can you post it as answer because I can't upvote de comments ? sizeof(Data) I see now that is 12 and sizeof(Data*) is 4

Comment: @AlexP Yeah ,not only probably , are for sure.As BLUEPIXY said ,that was the mistake.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data {
    int zi, luna, an;
} Data;

int main(void){
    FILE *pf = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(pf == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        return -1;
    }
    Data *d;
    int n;
    fscanf(pf, "%d", &n);
    d = calloc(n, sizeof(Data));//sizeof(Data* ) should be sizeof(Data)
    if(d == NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        return -2;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){//i <= n occurs out ouf bounds, In C 0 origin
        if(fscanf(pf, "%d/%d/%d", &d[i].zi, &d[i].luna,&d[i].an)!=3) break;
        printf("%d/%d/%d ", d[i].zi, d[i].luna, d[i].an);
    }
    fclose(pf);
    free(d);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/1buncu)

Comment: Thanks again,is there a second solution with fseek?Just wondering...

Comment: @KingTsunamy `fseek` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programming in C.

In C, loops are written like this:

```
for( i = 0;  i < n;  i++ )
```

***not*** like this:

```
for( i = 1;  i <= n;  i++ )
```

Comment: using 1..3 will cause problems if `d` is declared as `struct something d[3]`

Comment: It still crash ,I made it 1 because I thought it can do something,but it can't

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other errors pointed out in your program, the real reason for crash is: once you use `fprintf()`, the file pointer points to the end of the file. So essentially you're trying to use `fscanf` at the end of the file in your second call and hence the crash. To fix this, you can use `rewind()` after the `fprintf` call which rewinds the file pointer to previous location.

```
fscanf(pf,"%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(fscanf(pf,"%d/%d/%d",&(d[i].zi),&(d[i].luna),&(d[i].an))!=3) break;
    printf("%d/%d/%d ",d[i].zi,d[i].luna,d[i].an);
        fprintf(pf,"1111");
    }
    rewind(fp);
}
  fclose(pf);
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this is probably not what you want. Better way to go would be to keep track of bytes read so far and use `fseek` to get to your desired location after using `fprintf`.

Comment: You are right in detecting the mistake, but I do not think that your suggestion for a fix will work.  The OP will probably need to rethink what he/she is trying to do.  Reading from and at the same time writing to the same text file is flawed as a concept.

Comment: Adding rewind() will not work, since the fscanf call will fail due to the fact that "1111" does not match the specifier "%d/%d/&d". As @Mike says, the OP needs to rethink what he is trying to do.

Comment: rewind need the argument pf and it will refresh the file so the second and third line will never be read

Comment: Yes it is flawed idea indeed. But if he *really* wants to do it for some reason, his choices are either `rewind` or `fseek` and keeping track of bytes.

Comment: Regardless, reading from and writing to the same file is fraught with potential problems.

Comment: @FredK OP checks the return value of `fscanf` and breaks out of the loop on failure.

Comment: I updated the post a bit,with fseek(pf,0,SEEK_CUR); ,it returns -1073741819 (0xC0000005)